# Why am I unable to declare a vector global variable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, variables, vector, global-variables

Everything was compiling until I added `vector<Move> bestLine;`

search.h

```
#ifndef SEARCH_H
#define SEARCH_H

#include <vector>
#include "types.h"
#include "position.h"
#include "move.h"
#include "moves.h"

U8 searchDepth;
U8 searchCount;
vector<Move> bestLine; // The compiler doesn't like this.

void searchPosition(Position &P, U8 depth);
void searchMove(Move &M);

#endif
```

The errors I'm receiving are:

```
1>d:\test\search.h(12): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
1>d:\test\search.h(12): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>d:\test\search.cpp(30): error C2065: 'bestLine' : undeclared identifier
```

It seems that the compiler isn't recognizing `Move`, so `bestLine` isn't being declared. I thought it might be a circular dependency and tried declaring an incomplete type for `Move`, but it had no effect. Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually qualifying is not enough, although necessary:

```
std::vector<Move> bestLine;
```

This also constitutes a definition, and, if in a header, you risk having linker errors.

You should declare it `extern` and define it in a single implementation file:

```
//search.h
//...
extern std::vector<Move> bestLine;

//search.cpp
//...
std::vector<Move> bestLine;
```

Comment: Oddly, declaring it `static` resolved the linker errors, not `extern`.

Comment: @SvadHisthana Then you'll have a separate variable per translation unit (= usually one .cpp file), not a global one. For a truly global variable Luchian's solution is the correct one.

Comment: @SvadHisthana static is wrong if you want a global. You probably didn't define it in an implementation file, like I said you should.

Answer (score -3):

try adding the statement after the header file inclusion

```
using namespace std;
```

otherwise declare vector as

```
std::vector<Move>bestLine;
```

Comment: Please do not do this in header files.

Comment: I just changed it to `std::vector`.

Comment: @SvadHisthana that's won't be enough, the linker will complain.

Comment: The answer is suggesting the line goes 'after the header inclusion', so isn't actually suggesting it goes in the header